# Google Sign In didn't show permission window to Grant Access

Tags: android, google-signin

I want to use Google Sign In for my Android app, so naturally, I refer to https://developers.google.com/identity/sign-in/android/sign-in .

Everything works; when I first time run my app, and try to Sign In using Google, it will allow me to select which Google Account I want to use, then it will display a permission window with my app name. Then I press OK. Then I successfully sign in bla bla.

BUT.. then I go to https://myaccount.google.com/permissions and I revoke my app. OK right now I expect that when I try to google sign in in my app again, it will display the permission window again. But then, nothing happens when I try to Sign In using my google account. It just sign in without any problem (my GoogleSignInResult result returns true). Furthermore, when I go to https://myaccount.google.com/permissions, I don't see my app is being listed there.

What am I doing wrong here?

Comment: The result is cached. Try clearing the app data and do it again. You can probably also call sign out or disconnect methods to clear the cached account state. https://developers.google.com/identity/sign-in/android/disconnect

Comment: I cleared the app data, tried to uninstall and install back the app but it's still the same. Also tried using the signing out using the method you gave in the link but nothing changes.

Comment: I fixed this problem by adding acct.getServerAuthCode()  ....

Comment: @imin Hi, I have the same problem. How/where did you use getServerAuthCode() to fix this? Thanks.

Comment: I'm not getting the permissions screen. What should i do to get the permissions screen ?